# How to change alignItems of a component?

Tags: react-native

I have a `TouchableOpacity` with `absolute position` style, I need to change position icon to right.

**Now is :  [Icon] موقعیت من**

**I want :  موقعیت من  [Icon]**

> This is about Our language and for English just need change position of icon codes

How can I Change Icon position?

```
 <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.5} style={{position:'absolute',bottom:5,left:5,backgroundColor:'#ffffff',padding:3,borderRadius:3}} onPress={()=>this.componentDidMount()}>
                      <Text style={{textAlign:'right'}}>
                        <Ionicons name="md-locate" size={25} color="#ff9591" style={{right:0,paddingTop:5}}/>
                        <Text style={{left:0,fontFamily:'iransans',color:'#ff9591'}}>موقعیت من</Text>
                      </Text>
 </TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Organize your code like this.

```
    <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.5} style={{position:'absolute',bottom:5,left:5,backgroundColor:'#ffffff',
padding:3,borderRadius:3, flexDirection:'row'}} onPress={()=>this.componentDidMount()}>

      <Text style={{fontFamily:'iransans',color:'#ff9591',paddingTop:5}}>موقعیت من</Text>

      <Ionicons name="md-locate" size={25} color="#ff9591" style={{paddingTop:5}}/>

    </TouchableOpacity>
```